# Forgot local wandb email

Tags: python, local, wandb

I have been logging and browsing locally on wandb, but after some time and updates I got logged out and can't remember the email I used locally. How can I recover my local credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the email address associated with your local WandB instance by connecting to the Docker container and accessing the MySQL database. Follow these steps:

Connect to the WandB local Docker container by running:

```bash
docker exec -ti wandb-local bash
```

Access the MySQL database with the following command:

```bash
mysql -u wandb_local -p
```

When prompted, enter the default password: wandb_local.

Run the following commands in the MySQL console:

```sql
use wandb_local;
select id,email,auth_id,name,username from users;
```

This will display a table containing the email, username, and other information about the users in the WandB local instance.